# Calling .shell option of sqlite3 inside sqlite3 trigger

Tags: sqlite

```
create trigger t123  after update on t1
     begin
   .shell echo "hi";
    end;
```

It is showing syntax error near `.` How to correct it?
My aim is to execute a script by using trigger in sqlite.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) shows that only UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE/SELECT statements are allowed in a trigger body.
(And `.shell` is not an SQL statement anyway; it's implemented only by the `sqlite3` command-line shell.)

The only way to execute a script is to [create a user-defined function](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_function.html) that you can then execute by using it in a dummy query:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ...
BEGIN
  SELECT run_script('echo "hi"');
END;
```

(This trigger will fail if the database is used by some other program that does not install this function.)

Comment: is there any way to create persistent UDF,as far i searched and tried,the UDF's can be used till db is connected,after that it throws error if we try to access that UDF in sqlite terminal.

Comment: No; UDFs are created by the application, not by the database.

Comment: i know that UDF's  are created by applications using some sqlite api's ryt,??(sqlite_create_function()).is this function created by application doesn't work outside the scope of that application i.e if the application is stopped and not running??What i thought is the function created by this API will be written in Database

Comment: An UDF can be used only by the application itself.